# Java 8 parallel stream and ThreadLocal

Tags: java, java-8, threadpool, forkjoinpool

I am trying to figure out how can I copy a ThreadLocal value in Java 8 parallel stream.

So if we consider this:

```
    public class ThreadLocalTest {

        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            ThreadContext.set("MAIN");
            System.out.printf("Main Thread: %s\n", ThreadContext.get());

            IntStream.range(0,8).boxed().parallel().forEach(n -> {
                System.out.printf("Parallel Consumer - %d: %s\n", n, ThreadContext.get());
            });
        }

        private static class ThreadContext {
            private static ThreadLocal<String> val = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "empty");

            public ThreadContext() {
            }

            public static String get() {
                return val.get();
            }

            public static void set(String x) {
                ThreadContext.val.set(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which outputs

```
Main Thread: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 5: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 4: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 7: empty
Parallel Consumer - 3: empty
Parallel Consumer - 1: empty
Parallel Consumer - 6: empty
Parallel Consumer - 2: empty
Parallel Consumer - 0: MAIN
```

Is there a way for me to clone the ThreadLocal from main() method into the threads which are spawned for each parallel execution ?

Such so that my result is:

```
Main Thread: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 5: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 4: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 7: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 3: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 1: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 6: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 2: MAIN
Parallel Consumer - 0: MAIN
```

instead of the first one?

Comment: I wouldn't expect so.  But why is this `ThreadLocal` in the first place, instead of just created in your main method and then passed on explicitly to the lambda?

Comment: Are you trying to cross the streams? I've heard it would be bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[As Louis has stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926777/java-8-parallel-stream-and-threadlocal#comment55614607_33926777), your example can very well be reduced to capturing the value of a local variable in the lambda expression

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String value = "MAIN";
    System.out.printf("Main Thread: %s\n", value);

    IntStream.range(0,8).boxed().parallel().forEach(n -> {
        System.out.printf("Parallel Consumer - %d: %s\n", n, value);
    });
}
```

It's not obvious from your example what the full use case is.

If you know exactly which threads will be **started** from your main thread, you may consider using an [`InheritableThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html)

> This class extends `ThreadLocal` to provide **inheritance of values from
> parent thread to child thread**: when a child thread is created, the
> child receives initial values for all inheritable thread-local
> variables for which the parent has values.

In your case, declaring `val` as an `InheritableThreadLocal`, since the `Thread` instances created for `parallel()` within the `ForkJoinPool#commonPool()` are created lazily, they would all inherit from the value `set` in the `main` method (and thread).

This wouldn't be the case if you somehow used the `commonPool` (or whatever pool the `parallel` terminal operation was called on) before you set the `InhertiableThreadLocal` value in the origin thread.

Comment: Yes, my example wasn't giving too much information about the use case. The actual use case is together with some other code (apart of the parallel() consumer) and the ThreadLocal is being populated in a Servlet filter and then used in a Spring MVC controller, and some times cloned for various runnable implementations across the board (service calls, etc). So there will be various calls down the road which are ThreadContext.get(something). Thanks for explaining the InheritableThreadLocal, I will give it a try!